# How to unlock a Netezza database after restore?

Tags: restore, netezza, unlock

We are performing a production upgrade soon.  I want to do a restore of the current backups onto the Disaster Recovery system, but leave the databases locked so that the incrementals can be applied quickly if needed.

If no incremental is produced for a database, how do I take it out of the locked state?  Executing `nzrestore -dir <dir> -connector filesystem -db <db> -incremental REST -lockdb false` fails because there's no incremental to apply.  Therefore the database doesn't unlock.  Removing `-incremental REST` causes the command to try to perform a full restore again.

We are running version 11.2.1.6-IF1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

```
nzrestore -db <db> -unlockdb
```